# Question about quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics

Suppose a quadratic equation whose roots are 3 and -2, 
so the equation is (x-3)(x+2) = 0
So, from here we get, 
x-3 = 0 
and, 
x+2 = 0 
Since, both equations equal to zero, we can equate these two,
x-3 = x+2 
So, -3 = 2 ? 
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You used AND instead of OR.

Comment: I don't get it. Why shouldn't it be 'AND'?

Comment: $0*3=0$ but $3\neq 0$

Comment: I don't get you.

Comment: I have derived x - 3 = x + 2 , why is this equation wrong?

Comment: $x-3=0$ IF AND ONLY IF $x=3$.

Comment: now you got it?

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong when you say that

x-3=0 AND x+2=0

You correctly reduced the given quadratic to

(x-3)(x+2)=0

Hence this equation will be satisfied if and only if any ONE of the conditions are satisfied....ie....Either

x-3=0

OR

x+2=0

(Since 0x(any no.)=0)

Hence you get two solutions

x=3

AND

x=-2

Obviously x can take only a *single value at a time*.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood it. And can you explain that why do we write the quadratic equation as (x-a)(x-b)=0 if a and b are the two roots. I have just learned it. I don't know the proof/logic

Comment: We just factorise the given second degree expression into two factors.....from which we easily get the solutions of the given quadratic. Obviously all such expressions cannot be factorised into rational/integral factors....but anyways thats another case....which you will learn in coming years I guess.